# How to find and name contiguous non-zero entries in a sparse matrix in R?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, contiguous

My problem is conceptually simple.
I am looking for a computationally efficient solution of it (my own one I attach at the end).

Suppose we have a potentially very large sparse matrix like the one on the left below and want to 'name' every area of contiguous non-zero elements with a separate code (see matrix on the right)

```
1 1 1 . . . . .          1 1 1 . . . . .
1 1 1 . 1 1 . .          1 1 1 . 4 4 . .
1 1 1 . 1 1 . .          1 1 1 . 4 4 . .
. . . . 1 1 . .   --->   . . . . 4 4 . .
. . 1 1 . . 1 1          . . 3 3 . . 7 7
1 . 1 1 . . 1 1          2 . 3 3 . . 7 7
1 . . . 1 . . .          2 . . . 5 . . .
1 . . . . 1 1 1          2 . . . . 6 6 6
```

In my application the contiguous elements would form rectangles, lines or single points and they can only touch each other with the vertexes (i.e. there would be no irregular/non rectangular areas in the matrix).

The solution I imagined is to match the row and column indexes of the sparse matrix representation to a vector with the appropriate values (the 'name' codes). My solution uses several `for loops` and works fine for small to medium matrices but will fast get stuck in the loops as the dimensions of the matrix become large (>1000). It probably depends from the fact I'm not so advanced in R programming - I couldn't find any computational trick/function to solve it better.

Can anybody suggest a computationally more efficient way to do that in R?

My solution:

```
mySolution <- function(X){

  if (class(X) != "ngCMatrix") {stop("Input must be a Sparse Matrix")}
  ind <- which(X == TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)
  r <- ind[,1]
  c <- ind[,2]

  lr <- nrow(ind)
  for (i in 1:lr) {
    if(i == 1) {bk <- 1}
    else {
      if (r[i]-r[i-1] == 1){bk <- c(bk, bk[i-1])}
      else {bk <- c(bk, bk[i-1]+1)}
    }
  }

  for (LOOP in 1:(lr-1)) {
    tr <- r[LOOP]
    tc <- c[LOOP]
    for (j in (LOOP+1):lr){
      if (r[j] == tr) {
        if(c[j] == tc + 1) {bk[j] <- bk[LOOP]} 
      }
    }
  }

  val <- unique(bk)
  for (k in 1:lr){
    bk[k] <- which(val==bk[k])
  }

  return(sparseMatrix(i = r, j = c, x = bk))
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or pointer.

Comment: Might be a good use case for `Rcpp`. Your code seems straightforward enough to translate

Comment: @apom you might be right but I'm skimming through `Rcpp` vignettes right now, and if I need to know `C++` language as it seems, that's not for me unfortunately ...

Comment: Assuming `m` is your "ngCMatrix", you could try finding a way to make something like `sm = summary(m); sparseMatrix(i = sm$i, j = sm$j, x = cutree(hclust(dist(sm, "maximum")), h = 2))` work appropriately

Comment: @alexis_laz, I'm impressed - so elegant. Chapeau, I would have never found such a solution. I'm running a few simulations but it seems to work. Thank you for the enlightenment. :)

Comment: ... well, actually I talked a bit too early. I will still try to make it work appropriately but the clustering of areas joined by the vertex, or even larger than distance = 2 from border to border, simply misbehave...

Comment: @GiuGe : I know; couldn' find a way to make it work. On the same note, taking into account the "only rectangles" condition and, computing a custom distance `sm = as.matrix(summary(m)); d = as.dist(sapply(1:nrow(sm), function(i) rowSums(abs(sm[i, col(sm)] - sm))))`, using `sparseMatrix(i = sm[, "i"], j = sm[, "j"], x = cutree(hclust(d, "single"), h = 1))` seems to work fine for the current example, though I tend to believe that there 'll be many cases that break it.

Comment: @alexis_laz Bingo! This is it! You can change the computation of `d` into `d <- dist(sm, method = "manhattan")` because this is basically what you're doing there. Single linkage aggregation and a cut of the three at height 1 effectively distinguish areas which 'touch' each other at the vertex (and hence are 2 steps away in term of distance): as I said in my question this is the situation I have in my data, so this is fine. A couple of simulations with my function and your method say your method is faster by a factor of 4 with matrices 200x200. Why don't you publish your answer below? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relying heavily on the fact that all neighbouring elements to be grouped form only rectangles/lines/points, we see that elements of the matrix can be aggregated based on their `[row, col]` indices on the matrix by the relation `(abs(row1 - row2) + abs(col1 - col2)) < 2`.

So, starting with the `[row, col]` indices:

```
sm = as.matrix(summary(m))
```

We compute their distance, which -as noted by GiuGe- is actually the "manhattan" method:

```
d = dist(sm, "manhattan")
```

Single-linkage's property in clustering elements  on their nearest neighbour is useful here. Also, we can get a grouping of the elements by `cutree`ing on "h = 1" (where the distance of indices is "< 2"):

```
gr = cutree(hclust(d, "single"), h = 1)
```

Finally, we can wrap the above in a new sparse matrix:

```
sparseMatrix(i = sm[, "i"], j = sm[, "j"], x = gr)
#8 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                    
#[1,] 1 1 1 . . . . .
#[2,] 1 1 1 . 4 4 . .
#[3,] 1 1 1 . 4 4 . .
#[4,] . . . . 4 4 . .
#[5,] . . 3 3 . . 7 7
#[6,] 2 . 3 3 . . 7 7
#[7,] 2 . . . 5 . . .
#[8,] 2 . . . . 6 6 6
```

"m" used is:

```
library(Matrix)
m = new("ngCMatrix"
    , i = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L)
    , p = c(0L, 6L, 9L, 14L, 16L, 20L, 24L, 27L, 30L)
    , Dim = c(8L, 8L)
    , Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL)
    , factors = list()
)
```

**EDIT** *Feb 10 '17*

Another idea (and, again, considering the fact that neighbouring elements form only rectangles/lines/points) is to iterate -in ascending columns- through the `[row, col]` indices and, in each step, find the distance of each element of its nearest neighbour in current column and row. If a "< 2" distance is found then the element is grouped with its neighbour, else a new group is started. Wrapped into a function:

```
ff = function(x) 
{
    sm = as.matrix(summary(x))

    gr = integer(nrow(sm)); ngr = 0L ; gr[1] = ngr 

    lastSeenRow = integer(nrow(x))
    lastSeenCol = integer(ncol(x))

    for(k in 1:nrow(sm)) {
        kr = sm[k, 1]; kc = sm[k, 2]
        i = lastSeenRow[kr]
        j = lastSeenCol[kc]

        if(i && (abs(kc - sm[i, 2]) == 1)) gr[k] = gr[i]
        else if(j && (abs(kr - sm[j, 1]) == 1)) gr[k] = gr[j]  
             else { ngr = ngr + 1L; gr[k] = ngr } 

        lastSeenRow[kr] = k
        lastSeenCol[kc] = k        
    }

    sparseMatrix(i = sm[, "i"], j = sm[, "j"], x = gr)                 
}
```

And applied on "m":

```
ff(m)
#8 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                    
#[1,] 1 1 1 . . . . .
#[2,] 1 1 1 . 4 4 . .
#[3,] 1 1 1 . 4 4 . .
#[4,] . . . . 4 4 . .
#[5,] . . 3 3 . . 7 7
#[6,] 2 . 3 3 . . 7 7
#[7,] 2 . . . 5 . . .
#[8,] 2 . . . . 6 6 6
```

Also, it's convenient that both functions return groups in the same order, as we can check:

```
identical(mySolution(m), ff(m))
#[1] TRUE
```

On a, seemingly, more complex example:

```
mm = new("ngCMatrix"
    , i = c(25L, 26L, 27L, 25L, 29L, 25L, 25L, 17L, 18L, 26L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
14L, 17L, 18L, 25L, 27L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 17L, 18L, 23L, 26L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 10L, 17L, 18L, 9L, 11L, 17L, 18L, 10L, 17L, 18L, 3L, 
17L, 18L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 8L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 26L, 
8L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 15L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 21L, 22L, 1L, 
2L, 7L, 21L, 22L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 11L, 16L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 4L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 3L, 16L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 2L, 28L, 1L)
    , p = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 18L, 25L, 31L, 35L, 38L, 
42L, 44L, 46L, 51L, 61L, 66L, 68L, 71L, 75L, 79L, 84L, 88L, 96L, 
103L, 108L, 110L, 111L)
    , Dim = c(30L, 30L)
    , Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL)
    , factors = list()
)
identical(mySolution(mm), ff(mm))
#[1] TRUE
```

And a simple benchmark on a larger matrix:

```
times = 30 # times `dim(mm)`
MM2 = do.call(cbind, rep_len(list(do.call(rbind, rep_len(list(mm), times))), times))
dim(MM2)
#[1] 900 900

system.time({ ans1 = mySolution(MM2) })
#   user  system elapsed 
# 449.50    0.53  463.26

system.time({ ans2 = ff(MM2) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.51    0.00    0.52

identical(ans1, ans2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you @alexis_laz. I've been trying this code in the past days. The results are correct, and it is faster than my solution. Yet, with veeeery big matrices (>1000x1000) it can still choke the RAM when building the distance matrix. So new approaches are also welcome.

Comment: @GiuGe : Yeah, although "dist" does not save the whole distance matrix but its `lower.tri`, it -still- demands significant memory. I 've added another approach which, testing it on some cases, seems to be correct; hope i 've not missed something in the process.

Comment: Fantastic! @alexis_laz you're a genius! Thank you so much.