# Extract multiple data files within the same sheet

Tags: r, csv

**Update**:
Gone manual, cut and paste into multiple sheets. Would be great to find a workaround all the same.

**Question**:
Given the dummy data set below:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(8L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
9L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 3L), .Label = c("", "1", 
"12", "5", "Age", "Class A", "Height", "ï»¿Number of Boys", "More Boys", 
"More Girls"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"12", "2", "6", "Class B", "Time", "Weight"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("", "13", "3", 
    "7", "Class C", "Next", "Time"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 
    5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    6L, 2L), .Label = c("", "14", "4", "8", "Class D", "Day"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V7 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), V8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V10 = structure(c(5L, 
    4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1", "8", "Class E", "Number of Girls"
    ), class = "factor"), V11 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "2", "8", "Class F"), class = "factor"), V12 = structure(c(1L, 
    4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "3", "9", "Class G"), class = "factor"), 
    V13 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "0", "4", 
    "Class Q"), class = "factor"), V14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

This visually looks like(truncated):

```
               V1      V2      V3      V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9             V10     V11     V12     V13 V14
1  ï»¿Number of Boys                         NA NA NA NA NA Number of Girls                          NA
2            Class A Class B Class C Class D NA NA NA NA NA         Class E Class F Class G Class Q  NA
3                  1       2       3       4 NA NA NA NA NA               8       8       9       0  NA
4                  5       6       7       8 NA NA NA NA NA               1       2       3       4  NA
5                                            NA NA NA NA NA                                          NA
6                                            NA NA NA NA NA                                          NA
7                                            NA NA NA NA NA                                          NA
8                                            NA NA NA NA NA                                          NA
9          More Boys                         NA NA NA NA NA                                          NA
10               Age    Time    Next     Day NA NA NA NA NA                                          NA
11                 1       2       3       4 NA NA NA NA NA                                          NA
12                                           NA NA NA NA NA                                          NA
```

As can hopefully be seen, these are separate "files" on the same worksheet. I've looked for a quick way to scoop out the different data sets but haven't(yet). Could there be a work around?
My idea was to use a sequence based selection, say select every 20 rows but this will obviously fail if you have millions of rows?

**Expected Ouptut(with their respective rows)**

```
Three data sets: 
A: Number of Boys
B: Number of Girls
C: More Boys
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the different tables in the original excel-file defined as separate tables or named regions? If so, you can address these separately using e.g. `read.xlsx` package.

Comment: They're in the same sheet. Different names, separated by "gaps".

Answer (score 1):

Using @alexis_laz's solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42120347/6197649

```r
library(Matrix)

x <- !is.na(df) & df != ""
m <- Matrix(x)

#> 18 x 14 sparse Matrix of class "lgCMatrix"
#>    [[ suppressing 14 column names 'V1', 'V2', 'V3' ... ]]
#>                                  
#>  [1,] | . . . . . . . . | . . . .
#>  [2,] | | | | . . . . . | | | | .
#>  [3,] | | | | . . . . . | | | | .
#>  [4,] | | | | . . . . . | | | | .
#>  [5,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#>  [6,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#>  [7,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#>  [8,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#>  [9,] | . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [10,] | | | | . . . . . . . . . .
#> [11,] | | | | . . . . . . . . . .
#> [12,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [13,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [14,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [15,] . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [16,] | . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [17,] | | | | . . . . . . . . . .
#> [18,] | | | | . . . . . . . . . .

sm = as.matrix(summary(m))

d = dist(sm, "manhattan")

gr = cutree(hclust(d, "single"), h = 1)

res <- sparseMatrix(i = sm[, "i"], j = sm[, "j"], x = gr)

#> 18 x 13 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>                                
#>  [1,] 1 . . . . . . . . 4 . . .
#>  [2,] 1 1 1 1 . . . . . 4 4 4 4
#>  [3,] 1 1 1 1 . . . . . 4 4 4 4
#>  [4,] 1 1 1 1 . . . . . 4 4 4 4
#>  [5,] . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#>  [6,] . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#>  [7,] . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#>  [8,] . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#>  [9,] 2 . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [10,] 2 2 2 2 . . . . . . . . .
#> [11,] 2 2 2 2 . . . . . . . . .
#> [12,] . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [13,] . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [14,] . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [15,] . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [16,] 3 . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> [17,] 3 3 3 3 . . . . . . . . .
#> [18,] 3 3 3 3 . . . . . . . . .

res2 <- summary(res)

lapply(
  split(res2[, c("i", "j")], res2$x),
  function(area) {
    df[min(area$i):max(area$i), min(area$j):max(area$j), drop = FALSE]
  }
)

#> $`1`
#>                  V1      V2      V3      V4
#> 1 ï»¿Number of Boys                        
#> 2           Class A Class B Class C Class D
#> 3                 1       2       3       4
#> 4                 5       6       7       8
#> 
#> $`2`
#>           V1   V2   V3  V4
#> 9  More Boys              
#> 10       Age Time Next Day
#> 11         1    2    3   4
#> 
#> $`3`
#>            V1     V2   V3  V4
#> 16 More Girls                
#> 17     Height Weight Time Day
#> 18         12     12   13  14
#> 
#> $`4`
#>               V10     V11     V12     V13
#> 1 Number of Girls                        
#> 2         Class E Class F Class G Class Q
#> 3               8       8       9       0
#> 4               1       2       3       4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The following code creates a list of data.frames with column names beeing set correctly. It relies, however, on the fact that in your sheet "columns of tables" are separated by at least one empty column...

```
df <- apply(df, 2, function(x) gsub("^$|^ $", NA, x))
empty_cols <- sapply(1:ncol(df), function(i){length(which(is.na(df[, i])))==nrow(df)})
start_cols <- c(1, which(diff(empty_cols)==-1)+1)
if (is.na(df[1, 1])) start_cols <- start_cols[-1]
start_rows <- lapply(start_cols, function(i){
  start_rows <- c(1, which(diff(is.na(df[, i]))==-1)+1)
  if (is.na(df[1, i])) start_rows <- start_rows[-1]
  start_rows})

end_rows <- lapply(start_cols, function(i){
  end_rows <- c(1, which(diff(is.na(df[, i]))==1))
  if (!is.na(df[nrow(df), i])) end_rows <- c(end_rows, nrow(df))
  end_rows[-1]})

data.sets <- list()
for (i in 1:length(start_cols)) {
    for (j in 1:length(start_rows[[i]])){

      col <- start_cols[i]
      row <- start_rows[[i]][j]
      start_row <- row+1
      end_row <- end_rows[[i]][j]
      name <- df[row, col]
      ncol <- which(diff(is.na(df[row+1, col:ncol(df)]))==1)[1]
      end_col <- col+ncol-1
      column_names <- df[start_row, col:end_col]
      data <- df[(start_row+1):end_row, col:end_col]
      data <- matrix(data, ncol = length(col:end_col))
      data <- as.data.frame(data)
      names(data) <- column_names
      data.sets[[name]] <- data
    }
}


> data.sets
$`ï»¿Number of Boys`
  Class A Class B Class C Class D
1       1       2       3       4
2       5       6       7       8

$`More Boys`
  Age Time Next Day
1   1    2    3   4

$`More Girls`
  Height Weight Time Day
1     12     12   13  14

$`Number of Girls`
  Class E Class F Class G Class Q
1       8       8       9       0
2       1       2       3       4
```